# How to display number of search results found

Tags: php

This is my code. How can I output the number result when searching thanks

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

$search_value= $_GET['searchbox'];



//$sql="SELECT idemp,sn FROM employee 
/    /WHERE idemp like '%$search_value%' OR
//sn like '%$search_value%'";

$sql = "SELECT * from application where (leave_id like '%$search_value%' OR id_no like                 '%$search_value%' OR type_of_leave like '%$search_value%' OR date_of_filing like '%$search_value%')";

       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "Search results for '$search_value'";
       print "<br><br>";

       while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
.....
      close();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show total result with:

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

OR

```
echo $result->num_rows;
```